# MySQL - How to replace a given value from multiple columns when using SELECT?

Tags: mysql, select

I need to SELECT a set of rows of a given table whose structure looks like - 1º line is the name of columns

```
    A01    A02    A03    A04    A05  ... A200

  99999  99999     10    753  99999     99999
```

As you can see, it has about 200 columns. It uses 99999 to model a NULL or undefined value. So, in my SELECT, i need to replace those values with NULL or even a empty String. Is it possible by using a single SELECT or should i use something else ?

ATT: you could suggest UPDATE those values with NULL - and then SELECT -, but it is a legacy system which we cannot modify them

Comment: Can you show the exact table structure ? Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G` and show the top 10 lines and the bottom 10 lines.

Comment: You can create a view that expose the table with replacement of 99999 by NULL and issue your select in the new application on the view instead of the real table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IF(A01 = 99999, NULL, A01) AS A01,
       IF(A02 = 99999, NULL, A02) AS A02,
       ...
    FROM ...
```

(For empty string, use `''` instead of `NULL`.)